# Why does this program print 12?

Tags: python, break

```
for num in range(10,14):
    for i in range(2, num):
        if num%i == 1:
            print(num)
            break
```

The output of this program is:
10
11
12
13

I am confused about why the output contains 12? Because when num = 12, none of the values of i from the inner loop fulfills the if condition. So shouldn't the output be excluding 12? Can you please explain why is this happening?

Comment: Because `num % (num-1) == 1` for all `num` bigger than 2

Comment: `Because when num = 12, none of the values of i from the inner loop fulfills the if condition` What is `12 % 11`?

Comment: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit try pasting the code here and watching it step by step, it helps with basic function like this

Comment: @CS2020 Glad to hear that! try learning how to use a debugger, most ide's have a debugger built it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's simply debug this, you have following values:

```
num    i    num%i                   output
10     2        0 => do nothing  <nothing>
10     3        1 => print(num)         10
11     2        1 => print(num)         11
12     2        0 => do nothing  <nothing>
12     3        0 => do nothing  <nothing>
12     4        0 => do nothing  <nothing>
12     5        2 => do nothing  <nothing>
12     6        0 => do nothing  <nothing>
12     7        5 => do nothing  <nothing>
12     8        4 => do nothing  <nothing>
12     9        3 => do nothing  <nothing>
12    10        2 => do nothing  <nothing>
12    11        1 => print(num)         12
13     2        1 => print(num)         13
```

Do you understand the logic now?

Comment: Yes I do ! Thank you ! ^_^